# How to safely remove an action hook in child-theme?

Tags: wordpress

I am working on a WordPress installation called [PointFinder](https://themeforest.net/item/point-finder-directory-wordpress-theme/10298703). Items that are posted by users get deleted after some pre-defined period. My goal is to disable this behaviour. I already found the corresponding code lines and deactivated the `add_action` hook that triggers the periodically called function `pointfinder_clean_pending_orders()` in `schedule-config.php`, which works fine for the moment.

```
add_action( 'pointfinder_schedule_hooks_hourly', 'pointfinder_clean_pending_orders' );   // <--- commented out this line

function pointfinder_clean_pending_orders() {
    /* code that cleans-up ... */
}
```

How can I achieve the deactivation in my child-theme ? If I simply add a `remove_action` to `functions.php` in my child-theme, will that work? I am not sure what will be called first, `add_action` in `schedule-config.php` or my `remove_action` in `functions.php` ?

I only have access to the productive server and no testing environment and thus I am a bit reluctant regarding experiments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
add_action('init','remove_hourly_hook');
function remove_hourly_hook() {
    remove_action( 'pointfinder_schedule_hooks_hourly', 'pointfinder_clean_pending_orders' );
}
```

What this does is after WordPress is initialized (regardless of the order of functions.php being called), it will then remove the action.

Now, if the initial add_action is inside a its own hook, you will want to make sure your hook 'init' is changed to occur afterwards.

Comment: Thanks for answering! According to https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_action, there's no method signature of `remove_action` that takes a single argument only. Moreover, I don't have much scope for experiments, since I only have access to the productive webpage. Unfortunately no testing environment available, thus I need to be very sure that it will work, otherwise I am going to loose more data by the periodic deletion algorithm.

Comment: Thank you very much :) I will try this one.